# R apply function to calculate log diff of a dataframe

Tags: r, apply

I have a dataframe:

```
df1 <- data.frame(a=runif(10),b=runif(10),c=runif(10))
df1
```

I then tried to calculate the log diff of all the columns in the dataframe

```
df2 <- apply(df1,2,function(x) diff(log(df1[,x]), lag=1))
df2
```

but I get a an error.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Thanks that is it. Thank you for finding my error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anonymous function `function(x)` returns the value of that column and not its index, so we have to take the `log` on the 'x'

```
r1 <-apply(df1,2,function(x) diff(log(x), lag=1))
```

---

Another option is `colDiffs` after taking the `log` of the dataset

```
library(matrixStats)
r2 <- colDiffs(log(as.matrix(df1)))
all.equal(r1, r2, check.attributes=FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.